# How to hide a div if containt different value of variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i trying to hide a div's that not contains a specific value, i have a div that contains a table, inside of table have a span like this:

this is my libraries and css:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Ordenes - 99 Minutos</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="static/dashboard/v3/js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script src="static/dashboard/v3/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="static/dashboard/v3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="static/dashboard/v3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/dashboard/v3/style.css" type="text/css" />

    <link href="static/dashboard/v3/css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>
```

[image]

the code of it:

```
<div class="container-a">
                  <div class="container-b">
                    <div class="container-c">
                        <table border="1"style="width:98%">
                          <tr>
                            <td width="220" height="100">
                              1
                            </td>
                            <td width="200">
                              2
                            </td>
                            <td width="300">
                             <div id="step_form_1" class="order-steps">
                              <span>25/01/2016 13:30</span>
                              <div>
                            </td>
                            <td width="120">
                              4
                            </td>
                             <td width="120">
                              5
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </div>
                    <div class="side-color">
                    </div>
                    <div class="tam">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                                    <div class="container-b">
                    <div class="container-c">
                        <table border="1"style="width:98%">
                          <tr>
                            <td width="220" height="100">
                              1
                            </td>
                            <td width="200">
                              2
                            </td>
                            <td width="300">
                             <div id="step_form_1" class="order-steps">
                              <span>18/01/2016 13:30</span>
                              <div>
                            </td>
                            <td width="120">
                              4
                            </td>
                             <td width="120">
                              5
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </div>
                    <div class="side-color">
                    </div>
                    <div class="tam">
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

With Jquery i get the current date, be cause i try to compare the content of the div (date) with the current date, i write a slice to obtain only date witouth time:

```
var d = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', new Date());

var e = $("#step_form_1 span").html().slice(0,-6);
```

I trying to hide div's that not contains a specific date, for example if a div contains 25/01/2016 steel showing and the rest of it hide

Comment: It would help if you provided all of the jquery/javascript you're using as well as the different libraries.

Comment: I paste all of my head content, i hope can help you to understand my code

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of jquery `:contains()` selector to find if a specific element contains the text or not.

```
$(".container-c table tr td div.order-steps").each(function()
{
   $(this).find('span:contains("25/01/2016")').length > 0 ?
      $(this).show() : $(this).hide(); 
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/6x80vabm/3/

Comment: thank's for you support, i want to hide all the divs that not contains the date, not only the date, but thanks!

Comment: You could make this reusable by substituting `e.toString()` variable for the `"25/01/2016"`—ie the selector would be `$(this).find('span:contains(' + e.toString() + ')')`.

Comment: Is it correct if i put something like this <code>$(this).find('span:contains(' + today.toString() + ' ' + d2.toString() + ' ' + d3.toString() + ')') to check more dates?

Comment: Yes you can certainly do that. It basically checks if that span contains the occurrence of the text, just like .IndexOf() function in javascript.

Comment: Well i try my last comment but i can't find something, i dont know why, maybe :contains only accept one value not more than one